# How to sub-query on the "many" part in a one-to-many association?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a standard one-to-many association in two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### How do I query for messages that are last for users with name "John"?

I know I can use a joins to filter messages by user attributes. I am also convinced that the "last for that user" part of the query can be done with what is called an sql sub-query, but how exactly it is done is beyond me.

```
Message.joins(:user).where(users: {name: "John"}).<subquery?>
```

Comment: `User.find_by_name("John").messages` returns all messages by the user `John`

Comment: @SunnyK That it does, but there may be several users named "John", but with different surnames, etc. The example is trivialized for simplicity.

Comment: Then use the `id` of the particular user you are interested in. At least, `id`s are unique. You then use `find_by_id` as opposed to `find_by_name`